# Writing a closed polynomial from a difference table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Here is a difference table for a function $S(N)$. Your job is to fill in the table, and then write out the closed polynomial expression corresponding to $S(N)$. The third level difference row is assumed to be a constant of $1$.

```
    N    0 1 2 3 4 5
    S(N) 2 - - - - - 
    ∆    0 - - - - -
    ∆2   3 - - - - - 
    ∆3   1 1 1 1 1 1
```

---

I solved the table to get the following:

```
    N    0 1 2  3  4  5
    S(N) 2 2 5 12 24 42 
    ∆    0 3 7 12 18 25
    ∆2   3 4 5  6  7  8
    ∆3   1 1 1  1  1  1
```

But I'm completely lost on how to write out the closed form polynomial. Can someone get me started?

Comment: [Read this link.](http://mathforum.org/mathimages/index.php/Difference_Tables) You can use the part "Newton's interpolation formula".

Comment: That seems to be a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083119/how-to-use-a-difference-table-to-find-a-formula-for-a-given-sequence.