# Find general term of a sequence ....

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $$a_1=2,a_2=6,a_3=12,a_4=20,....$$ be a sequence. What is $a_n$?

Comment: Not that you would need to do so for this sequence, but a great place to look up sequences is the OEIS. Check it out!

Comment: @Valborg -Please more guide.

Comment: If you do not have more information on the structure of $a_n$ you cannot conclude. You may guess what could be the right answer, but there are infinitely many "good" formulas which will give you these four initial terms.

Comment: Have a look at : http://oeis.org/ that will in fact give you different solutions, $a_n=n(n+1)$ being the most simple to describe...

Comment: @ JeanMarie, this shoul be an answer (of course, with additon that there exists infinite many other solutions)

Comment: This question is not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935002/baffled-by-resolving-number-list). While it's not about the same sequence, it discusses the same issues, and some useful methods to get a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n2k=n(n+1)$.

The sequence is [A002378](http://oeis.org/A002378): $2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90, 110,\dots$.

However, this is only one of the possible answers. Consider the sequence [A045619](http://oeis.org/A045619), i.e. the increasing sequence of numbers that are the products of two or more consecutive positive integers. It starts in the same way 2,6,12,20, but the next one is $2\cdot 3 \cdot 4=24$.

More terms are:
$2, 6, 12, 20, 24, 30, 42, 56, 60, 72, 90, 110, \dots$.

Comment: We should refrain from simply providing answers on this site. We are here to teach and help people understand math, not do their homework for them.

Comment: You are not useful if you simply solve people's homework for them. No one gains anything by that.

Comment: Facetiousness does not become you. This isn't about wisdom, it's about the community guidelines regarding problems that are most likely homework. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/106/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-homework-questions

Answer (score 4):

Look at the differences formed by two consecutive terms:
\begin{align}
a_2-a_1&=6-2=4\\
a_3-a_2&=12-6=6\\
a_4-a_3&=20-12=8
\end{align}
Each time we take the difference of two consecutive terms the result increases by $2$:
\begin{align}
a_2-a_1&=2\times 2\\
a_3-a_2&=2\times 3\\
a_4-a_3&=2\times 4\\
\dots&\quad\text{so we see }\\
a_{n}-a_{n-1}&=2\times n
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
a_2&=a_1+2\times 2\\
a_3&=a_2+2\times 3\\
a_4&=a_3+2\times 4\\
\dots&\\
a_{n}&=a_{n-1}+2\times n
\end{align}
Hence $a_n=a_{n-1}+2\times n=a_{n-2}+2\times(n-1)+2\times n\dots=2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=2\frac12n(n+1)=n(n+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

One of the simplest ways of attempting to extrapolate a formula for a sequence of numbers, particularly if there are so few terms given, is to try and identify if there is a point beyond which the forward difference operator appears to return a constant sequence. Try that out.